# Formatting spaces in print

Tags: python

I am trying to create a new print function in such a way that it prints colored text.
`"\033[1;31m"` make the cursor print in red and `"\033[0;0m"` reverts it back.

The color changing works perfectly but built-in print function is printing a space between every instance. How this space can be avoided?

I know about `sep` and `end` but using `sep=''` will change the behaviour of the whole print function. I only want no gap between the leftmost letter and margin.

```py
from builtins import print as b_print

def print(*args, **kwargs):
    b_print("\033[1;31m", *args, "\033[0;0m", **kwargs)
```

Output

```
print("Hello world")
>>><Space><red>Hello world</red>
```

Required

```
>>><red>Hello world</red>
```

What doesn't work

```
b_print("\033[1;31m", '\r', *args, "\033[0;0m", **kwargs)
# as there will be one more tab after \r

b_print("\033[1;31m", *args, "\033[0;0m", **kwargs, sep='')
# as it enforces seperator to be '' between all the args.
from builtins import print as p

b_print("\033[1;31m", '\b', *args,"\033[0;0m", **kwargs)
# as creating a new argument create a new space character
```

Comment: Maybe this is beside the point, but it's not `<Tab><red>Hello world</red>`, it's `<red><space/>Hello world<space/></red>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a bit more of the work manually: Take a `sep` parameter, convert `*args` to `str`, and join on `sep`.

```
from builtins import print as b_print

def print(*args, sep=' ', **kwargs):
    b_print("\033[1;31m" + sep.join(map(str, args)) + "\033[m", **kwargs)

print("Hello", "world", 7, sep='-')
```

Demo:

```
print("Hello", "world", 7, sep='-', end='x')
```

Output is like:

```
<red>Hello-world-7</red>x
```